# Recoding a string variable (e.g. "815") to a time variable (08:15) in R

Tags: r, datetime

I am looking for help recoding a string variable to be correctly formatted as a time variable using r. I have daily diary data for ~ 450 individuals, over the course of a week. They self-reported their bed and wake times, and I am trying to do 2 things with the data 1) see how bed and wake times vary over the course of the week, and 2) calculate 'sleep duration'; the number of hours that elapses between these bed and wake times.

My problem is finding a way to reformat the data. The bed and wake times are currently string variables, with no colon between hh and mm ("815" would mean 8:15 AM; "2345" would mean 11:45 PM; "15" would mean 12:15 AM). I don't necessarily care about getting the AM/PM in there, it's fine if everything gets reformatted to something like "23:45".

I cannot figure out which package/function/creative workaround would best be able to help with this. I did see some packages like chron or lubridate, but those functions seem like they would be more helpful for my second problem, calculating the time difference between the two variables. But I do need help recoding this string variable to something usable.

Thank you for any advice or help!!!

Comment: Do you have strings "815" or "815 AM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pad 0 to make the width 4 and then use `as.ITime` to convert to Time class

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
out <- as.ITime(str_replace(str_pad("815", width = 4, pad = 0), "(\\d{2})", "\\1:"))
str(out)
#'ITime' int 08:15:00
out
#[1] "08:15:00"
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
strptime(sub("(\\d{2})", "\\1:", sprintf("%04s", "815")), format = '%H:%M')
#[1] "2020-02-15 08:15:00 EST"
```

Comment: @RuiBarradas. sorry, couldn't reproduce the issue.  May be any locale issue

Comment: Maybe. But if I change to `sprintf("%04d", 815)` it works. I'll see what's going on.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  Could be some behavior change in `R 3.6.2` ( i am using that version)

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have these times:

```r
times <- c("345", "600", "1159", "1502", "2359")
```

Then we can define a simple function:

```
as_time <- function(t) gsub("(^\\d:)", "0\\1", gsub("(\\d{2}$)", ":\\1", t))
```

So we can do

```
as_time(times)
#> [1] "03:45" "06:00" "11:59" "15:02" "23:59"
```